# Gorm not required `belongs to`

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have this model:

```
type Order struct {
    ID                    uint64             `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    UserPaymentMethodID   uint64             `json:"payment_method_id"`
    UserPaymentMethod     *UserPaymentMethod
}
```

Is it possible to have not required `belongs to` for UserPaymentMethod column? I don't have to have constraints for this column.
PS. I want to use constraints for other columns

Answer (score 3):

Gorm by default makes columns nullable, that means that the belongs-to relationship is not required unless you tag that field as NOT NULL.

However, you'll get an error when creating an Order with a zero-valued UserPaymentMethodID since of course UserPaymentMethod 0 doesn't exist. What you need is simply to allow a null-value for this field by making it a pointer:

```golang
type Order struct {
    ID                    uint64             `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    UserPaymentMethodID   *uint64             `json:"payment_method_id"`
    UserPaymentMethod     *UserPaymentMethod
}

err := db.Create(&Order{}).Error // should work
```